# Using AWS API Gateway for Lumen based REST API Service with Passport authentication hosted in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, lumen, laravel-passport

I am entirely newbie in Amazon Web services. Currently i am developed a REST API service using Laravel's micro frameworks called Lumen. I am using passport for token based authentication and all that working fine. I need a proxy server to hide my actual endpoints and do some other functionality so i am planning to use AWS API Proxy Gateway and host the API endpoints in EC2 instance.

i went through [Build an API with HTTP Proxy Integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html) from Aws documentation. but there is nothing about using a custom authentication using Oauth.

My Doubts are

1. How to use Passport authentication when using AWS API Gateway
2. Is there any good method to hide my REST Endpoint from customer and need a way to change the proxy end point from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Laravel ecosystem, but:

- if passport expose something like an OpenId Connect you could use Cognito Federated Identities for, precisely, federate your identity, and associate the authorized identities with a given IAM role and unauthorized with another role;
- you can use an Api Gateway Custom Authorizer to perform fully customizable auth;

Try expanding your question so we could add more details...

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, like what BAD_SEED said, you can use API Gateway Lambda authorizer (formerly known as the custom authorizer) to do any logic to verify the token, since it's just a javascript package.

So, one option is like what auth0 does in (https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/aws-api-gateway/custom-authorizers/part-3) and (https://github.com/auth0-samples/jwt-rsa-aws-custom-authorizer). Their sample authorizer does followings:

- It confirms that an OAuth2 bearer token has been passed via the Authorization header.
- It confirms that the token is a JWT that has been signed using the RS256 algorithm with a specific public key
- It obtains the public key by inspecting the configuration returned by a configured JWKS endpoint
- It also ensures that the JWT has the required Issuer (iss claim) and Audience (aud claim)

But unfortunately, Passport does not support JWKS endpoint (which exposes public key for the token signature). So you may have to expose it by yourself.

Another option is much easier, you just make a token verification endpoint in your application, something like /users/me, and protect it with auth middleware. Then in your Lambda authorizer, call it with the token in the request to your other micro service endpoints. By this way, all token verification stuff is left to Passport, and the authorizer just executes policy based on the result of the verification.

2. Not very sure about what you want to reach, but API Gateway is just a proxy, so you can certainly change backend side endpoints for its frontend one, which is better not changing so often.